# What's better solution to sync images from database to web service and mobile application

Tags: java, json, base64, blob, synchronization

Whats the better solution to sync images according with path:

- Database - Web Service - Mobile Application

In my database, I have a **blob field** as images. So, I need the to transfer images for web service and mobile application.

I found the solution (attempt) but large images always return out of memory. Solution below:

- In my web service, I use the json API to store the blob images to integrate. See, I create image as base64 thats no problem for small images but large images (2000 items), triggers out of memory. So, my code below:

  ```
  public void getImages(String date) throws Exception {

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

  if (date != null)  {

      try {
          Class.forName(DRIVER);
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

          Statement s = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select * from images");

          while (r.next()) {
              JSONObject o = new JSONObject();

              byte[] imageBytes = r.getBytes("image");
              String imageBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes);
              o.put("image", imageBase64);

              jsonArray.put(o);
          }

          jsonObject.put("images", jsonArray);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- In my mobile application, read the json and decode base64 to each image after show image. So, I dont need to store the images in mobile disk or web service disk.

The mobile application will to work offline. Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Don't encode your images directly into JSON.  Rather return a server URL that separately serves up the image.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't encode your images directly into JSON. Rather return a server URL that separately serves up the image.

Tip of @Alan Krueger. It's better solution, encode images in json is bad idea.